# rich text editor is not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, wysihtml5

I try to integrate the rich text editor plugin into my project (laravel5.0 and the associated bootstrap version), but the visual rendering is not good ... it shows some button in white.

css include

```
   <link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/css.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/jquery.dataTables.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

textaera declaration

```
<textarea class="richtext" name="comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

JS include

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery-3.3.1.js') }}">`</script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.dataTables.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $('.richtext').wysihtml5();
</script>
```

expected
[image: expected result]
current result
[image]

Comment: well we can't really help you with this. It seems like some imports are not good or you haven't imported everything needed.

Comment: ideas for a simpler plugin to use???

Comment: Here on SO we do not recommend plugins/books/tutorials etc. Please read the StackOverflow rules first. Good luck

Comment: okay, thanks i was not aware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include all the js files and sequence of files of Js and CSS also matters in every case. Here is the fiddle, I have created, it's working properly.

You will have to include another js file at the end.

```
https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.min.js
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AsfiTanoli/41a0gyef/)

Comment: `<link href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` content bootstrap.min.css